# Is there any language can get the name of a local variable or passing parameter?

Tags: reflection

I'm looking for a language which "knows" itself very well.

Since I don't know is there such a language or what it is, I use Java here for example.

For example, it can get the "name" defined for a local variable.

```
String google = "http://google.com";
System.out.println(google.???);
// it prints `google`
```

Or get the passing parameter names:

```
void hello(String name) {
   System.out.println(name.???);
}

String jeff = "My name is Jeff";
hello(jeff);
// it prints `jeff`, not `My name is Jeff`
```

Is there any language has such power?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for java and introspection. You can get the name and type of properties, methods names and there arguments. Objective-c has similar features.

Comment: No, java can't get the name of a local variable, or the name of passing parameters in my example.

Comment: If you want to know the name of passing parameter like in your example, then You'll have to define your own class that have a "name" member in it.

Comment: I'm looking for a language has built-in support.

Comment: Here are a few examples. https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-dyn0603/. Many Interpreter based languages (Lisp/Scheme) provide more.

Answer (score 1):

This is called "Reflection".
Most modern languages have such a feature.

- PHP : http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php
- Java : http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/

Comment: I don't know PHP, but I know that java can't do the things in my example.